# Breaking statements and prove the given conclusion using rules of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference

I am learning inference and rules.

Currently trying to break statements out of this

Rules: A student's academic record cannot be shared without the student's consent. Academic records include grades, financial records or disciplinary records. 
Fact: A Student's disciplinary record is shared. 
Conclusion: The student gave consent to share his academic record.

This is how I am trying to create statements.

P = A student's academic record share

Q = Student's consent

R = include grades

S = financial records

T = disciplinary records